# Properties of exponents with logarithims

Tags: calculus

Does $$e^{x(\ln(\ln(1/x^2)))}$$
equal
$$ e^{\ln(x(\ln(1/x^2)))}$$

?

I'm having trouble taking the limit of $\ln(1/x^2)^x$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

I know that I should put the function in terms of $e$. After doing that, I'm not sure where to put my limit notation. After the $e$ or before the e?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do
$$e^{x\ln\ln\frac{1}{x^2}} = e^{\ln\left(\left(\ln\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x\right)} = \left(\ln\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^x.$$

If you are taking the limit as $x\rightarrow 0$ then you can pull this limit inside of the $\exp$ function. Specifically,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} e^{f(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)}.$$